# Three sprite node collision

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

I have a shooter app that is crashing when the bullet hits two overlapping nodes. I've tried everything, I tried checking if the bodies were nil but it wouldnt allow me, I'm not sure how to make this work anymore. here's the code:

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB

        }
        else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }

        if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & photonCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & alientCategory) != 0){
            aliensCollideWithBullets(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, alien: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
            //            firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
            //            secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()
        }



    }
    func aliensCollideWithBullets(torpedo:SKSpriteNode, alien:SKSpriteNode) {

        print("hit")

        torpedo.removeFromParent()
        alien.removeFromParent()
        aliensDestroyed++
        trumpsDestroyedLabel.text = "\(aliensDestroyed) Trumps"

        if (aliensDestroyed > 10) {
        }
    }
```

the line crashing is:

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & photonCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & alientCategory) != 0){
            aliensCollideWithBullets(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, alien: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
            //            firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
            //            secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual error message when app crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check bodyA and bodyB for nil. I had the same issue and solved it with this line of code:

```
if contact.bodyA.node != nil && contact.bodyB.node != nil
```